# Query TFS2010 for Test Cases without steps

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010, tfs-query

I'm copying test cases from one project to another in TFS2010.  Some of the test cases have a state of "Ready" and they have no steps.  I would like to make sure that those test cases can easily be found so I can change their state back to "Design". I was hoping to be able to build a query like:

Team Project = @Project
AND Area Path Under @Project
AND Work Item Type = Test Case
AND State = Ready
AND Steps =

I noticed when I chose Steps as the field that the Operator choices became "Contains" and "Does Not Contain".  Does anyone know any way to build a query that will bring back the results I'm looking for?  I'm not aware of any other Field that would be usable for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hack of a solution, but one that works:

```
AND Steps Does Not Contain a*
AND Steps Does Not Contain b*
...
AND Steps Does Not contain z*
```

This appears to accomplish the task.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use only vowels as a constraint.